# guard-coffee seems to cause guard-shell to execute twice

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, guard

I have guard (the ruby gem) setup and working it seems on my Mac and setting up a guard from guard-coffee and guard-shell seem to work fine. Here is the related section of my Guardfile below

```
guard 'coffeescript', :input => 'src/javascripts', :output => 'public/javascripts'
guard 'shell' do
    watch( %r{^public/.+\.(js|css)$} ) do |m|
        puts m.inspect
        if m[1] == 'js'
            puts 'a js is new!'
        else
            puts 'a css is new!'
        end
        puts %x{ echo #{File.mtime(m[0])} }
    end
end
```

Which seems to output 'a js is new' twice if I edit a coffeescript file. With debug on it seems to run after

```
13:39:23 - DEBUG - Hook :run_on_changes_begin executed for Guard::CoffeeScript
13:39:23 - INFO - Compile src/javascripts/blah.coffee
13:39:23 - INFO - 01:39:23 PM Successfully generated public/javascripts/blah.js
["public/javascripts/blah.js", "js"]
a js is new!
```

and

```
13:39:23 - DEBUG - Hook :run_on_changes_end executed for Guard::CoffeeScript
["public/javascripts/blah.js", "js"]
a js is new!
```

It does seem to only fire once if I edit the blah.js file directly. I was a little confused by how hooks work, can I key into a hook from another guard? Should I just run this code in a callback in the coffeescript guard? I was trying to use groups and only do the shell part if I was in a group and didn't want to have to repeat the coffee guard in the case where I would use a callback instead.

Any thoughts on how I can stop triggering the shell guard twice when the coffe one fires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to Guard 1.0.0, new files created and updated from a Guard plugin did not trigger a subsequent file change for other plugins. This was a problem for example with the CoffeeScript and LiveReload plugins: When a JavaScript file has been updated, then LiveReload did not reload the file. As a workaround I added some [manual file trigger code](https://github.com/guard/guard-coffeescript/blob/master/lib/guard/coffeescript.rb#L88-98). With the [Listen](https://github.com/guard/listen) gem this limitation has been removed, thus the CoffeeScript plugin triggers file changes twice.

I [removed](https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-coffeescript/commit/d29df33ee35d71cae5507e6888791492bdfcf788) it on my master branch. Can you please give it a try before I release a new gem? You can do this easily by using my master branch by adding:

`gem 'guard-coffeescript', :github => 'netzpirat/guard-coffeescript', :branch => 'master'`

to your `Gemfile`. I'll release a new gem asap when it works fine.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! Thanks for the follow up :) I am loving guard so far and I'll hopefully dig more into it soon. Also since I just did a 'bundle update' I also pulled down guard 1.5.1 if that effected anything as well. I am traveling this weekend or I would have seen this sooner.